# Couldn't load plugin 'processing' on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qgis-processing

I installed QGIS (2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, d94c044) using both the stand alone installer and the OSgeo4w installer and seem to have an issue with the processing plugin. At first I thought that there was a Python path issue, but now I am wondering if everything installed correctly. I don't know where the libraries live, so I would like some help debuging this issue.

Here is what I know:

1. I get the error message below when I start up QGIS
2. The following folders do not exist on my computer:

   ```
   C:\Users\gstein/.qgis2/python
   C:\Users\gstein/.qgis2/python/plugins
   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\python27.zip
   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
   C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
   ```

Any thoughts about what may be wrong?

**Error Message**

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' from ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\Users\gstein/.qgis2/python', 'C:\Users\gstein/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\bin', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Scripts', 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 182, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 20, in 
    from processing.tools.general import runalg, runandload, alghelp, alglist, algoptions, load, extent, getobject   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 43, in 
    from processing.algs.QGISAlgorithmProvider import QGISAlgorithmProvider   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\QGISAlgorithmProvider.py", line 86, in 
    from processing.algs.CreateConstantRaster import CreateConstantRaster   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\CreateConstantRaster.py", line 1, in 
    from processing.core.RasterWriter import RasterWriter   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\RasterWriter.py", line 28, in 
    import numpy   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in 
    import add_newdocs   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from type_check import *   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in 
    import multiarray   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in
_import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, d94c044

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\\Users\\gstein/.qgis2/python', 'C:\\Users\\gstein/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\arcpy', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have Python27 twice in your path, once in QGIS and one in root, maybe installed by ARCGIS. This might raise problems.

I did not get happy with the QGIS 64bit builds, and am now working with the 32bit standalone build (on Windows 7 64bit). I did **not** update the plugin from the standalone version. Maybe that solves your problem too.

The processing plugin files are located under .qgis2/processing, not .qgis2/python/plugins as it was in QGIS 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the latest version of the processing plugin.

I went to upgrade my own processing plugin in the 64bit version and received a similar error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' from ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\Users\heikki.vesanto/.qgis2/python', 'C:\Users\heikki.vesanto/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\bin', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\bin', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 182, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\heikki.vesanto/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\heikki.vesanto/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 35, in 
    from processing.gui.AlgorithmExecutor import AlgorithmExecutor
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named AlgorithmExecutor

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, d94c044

Python path: ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\\Users\\heikki.vesanto/.qgis2/python', 'C:\\Users\\heikki.vesanto/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\bin', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Should be reported on:
https://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues